# BeautifulSoup next_sibling returning None

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

For some reason item.next_sibling is returning None even though I can clearly see a sibling in the html. (item.next_sibling.next_sibling is what I want to do, but it's giving me an error since tag.next_sibling is None). Why is this happening?

The html where I'm having this issue is when scraping the list of films and their information from the wikipedia page 2015 in film. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_in_film

My code is working fine for all movies except for The Hateful Eight, where I'm getting None for siblings. One next_sibling should return whitespace, and two should return 'The Weinstein Company'

```
titles = soup.find_all('tr')
    for tag in titles:
        for item in tag.find_all('i'):
            if item.a and item.parent.parent.li == None and item.parent.attrs == {}:
                print item.a.text
                print item.parent.next_sibling
```

I'm using the wikipedia python library, but I don't believe there is a way to get information from tables, so I'm using it to get the html and then running the above.

Comment: What is your expected output?  You say you want `tag.next_sibling.nextsibling` but in the code the closest thing you have is `print item.parent.next_sibling`.  Please add expected output for the Hateful Eight

Comment: Edited. I used tag originally to match the documentation but I see it may have been confusing. item.parent.next_sibling should return whitespace. What I want to do is item.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling, which should return 'The Weinstein Company', but I can't do it when item.parent.next_sibling returns None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling` will return the tag, then you can get the name from that.  I cannot reproduce your failure at The Hateful Eight.

This is working in Python 3.3:

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_in_film"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

titles = soup.find_all('tr')
for tag in titles:
    for item in tag.find_all('i'):
        if item.a and item.parent.parent.li == None and item.parent.attrs == {}:
            print(item.a.text)
            print(item.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
```

Produces:

```
.....
Point Break
Warner Bros. / Lionsgate
The Hateful Eight
The Weinstein Company
The Revenant
20th Century Fox / Regency Enterprises / RatPac Entertainment
```

Comment: Argh ok, thank you for checking. That makes sense because I can see it in the html. Perhaps it's because I'm using the wikipedia library instead of urllib to get the html? I think I'm going to take a look when I get home to see if I can spot a difference in that section.